# PHP + Javascript how to place iframe correctly

Tags: javascript, php

How can I correctly place iframe using javascript in PHP? I tried code below but I received only empty iframe.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo '<script  type="text/javascript">
i = document.createElement("iframe");
i.setAttribute("src", "http://google.com");
document.body.appendChild(i);
</script>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your code works fine, no need of additional changes.

only thing is `google.com` doesn't allow you to call it on iframe. try your domain, it will work for sure.